# How to solve parameters in MYSQLi?

Tags: php

I am having a problem in my php file named JO-dashboard.php. It displays the error presented below the code.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$link = connectToDB();
$strXML = "<chart caption='Factory Output report' subCaption='By Quantity'   pieSliceDepth='30' showBorder='1' formatNumberScale='0' numberSuffix=' Units'>";   

$strQuery = "select DISTINCT profile from vgprofile";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $strQuery) or die(mysqli_error());

if($result) {
    while ($ors = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $strQuery = "select sum(MT) as totalLM from tbljocreator where PROFILE =" .    $ors['profile'];
        $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $strQuery) or die(mysqli_error());
        $getresult2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2); 
        $strXML .= "<set label='" . $ors['profile'] . "' value ='" . $getresult2['totalLM'] . "'  />";
        mysqli_free_result($result2);
    }
}
mysqli_close($link);
$strXML .= "</chart>";

echo renderChart("FusionCharts/Column3D.swf", "", $strXML, "JoCreator", 450, 300, false, true);

?>
```

THE ERROR IS IN:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $strQuery) or die(mysqli_error());
```

In the browser it shows:

```
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\LearningFusionCharts\MyFirstChart\JO-dashboard.php on line 29
```

Comment: Using `mysqli_*()` doesn't help if you use it incorrectly.

Comment: Why not read the manual page http://us2.php.net/mysqli_error

Comment: I am using those codes in my previous file. and they are working. it seems that it has a problem in computing the values in the TABLE tbljocreator beacause it has almost 6000 rows.

Comment: sorry for this usual problem for you guys but it became big deal to me because those codes are working when I used other tables

Answer (score 1):

the `mysqli_error` function requires a parameter. https://www.php.net/mysqli_error

p.s clean up your code and using tabs :)

Answer (score 1):

---

### The initial problem

You have to pass the connection object to the function `mysqli_error`, like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $strQuery) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

And this...

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $strQuery) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Note: your code must have another problem that will be revealed after you do this. PHP wouldn't be executing the part of `mysqli_error` if there weren't an error in the query or something related to it.

---

**The hidden problem**

In fact, I have reasons to think* the problem is that `$ors['profile']` is string, and therefore it should be between quotation marks in the query string:

```
$strQuery = 'select sum(MT) as totalLM from tbljocreator where PROFILE = "' . $ors['profile'] . '"';
```

*: This was confirmed in the comments. The error was:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'RIVETS' at line 1

In this case `RIVETS` is the value of `$ors['profile']` and evidently it is an string, ergo it must go between quotation marks...but that doesn't mean it is safe.

---

### SQL Injection

We could say that your code is correct, the same code will probably work is the data where different. Yet, since the values you are putting in the query string may not be entirely safe (even with the data comming from the database), you will have to escape the dangerous characters.

This is put in evidence by the error you got:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"CUTTING DISC 4""' at line 1

In this case, the variable `$ors['profile']` got the string `CUTTING DISC 4"`. This value is comming from the database and is causes a problem. It contains `4"` meaning four inches, but Mysql sees the quotation marks (`"`) and thinks that that is the end of the string, and tries to interpret whatever comes after the quotation marks as SQL.

If this input weren't from the database, but form the user... it would be worst... a malicious user could take adventage of it to execute arbitrary commands in the database. The potential of this kind of attack is overwhelming.

I recommend the video [Hacking Websites with SQL Injection - Computerphile](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jKylhJtPmI), it is a very good introduction to SQL injection for those beginners to web security, database security or information security in general. To learn more about what can be potentially be done with this kind of attack, read [SQL Injection Walkthrough (DVWA)](http://www.hackyeah.com/2010/05/hack-yeah-sql-injection-walkthrough-dvwa/) by Trenton Ivey.

---

**Preventing SQL Injection - The old way**

The old way to solve this problem is to escape the characters. SQL allows to do so by using the backslash character (`\`). So, in this example you would have to pass `4\"` instead of `4"`. But that is the tip of the iceberg, there are plenty of security problems with it.

Something you could do for ease of migration is to declare a function to sanitize the data you send to the database, the idea is to escape any possibly treating character... in fact there is a function for that in PHP ([`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)):

```
$strQuery = 'select sum(MT) as totalLM from tbljocreator where PROFILE = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($ors['profile']) . '"';
```

---

**The problems with the old way**

But `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated and should not be used in new development (you would notice it is not form mysqli... ), this function has some quirks of itself too... for example there is no way to tell that function what character encoding you are using (it uses whatever the databases is using), and there has been reports of problems with it when using multibyte characters. That is the old way to solve this.

Here goes another recommendation: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky. I understand if you don't want to read... get another video: [Characters, Symbols and the Unicode Miracle - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4)

---

**Preventing SQL Injection - The new and improved way**

With that said, the correct solution is to migrate to prepared statements, they are not really that hard with mysqli, it would be something like this:

```
$strQuery = 'select sum(MT) as totalLM from tbljocreator where PROFILE = ?';
if($stmt = $link->prepare($strQuery))
{
    //s for string
    //i for integer
    //d for double (or float)
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $ors['profile']);
    if (!$stmt->execute())
    {
    die mysqli_error($link);
    }
}
else
{
    die mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Read more about [Prepared Statements at PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: after I put the $link

the browse shows the error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RIVETS' at line 1

what must be the problem? thanks.

Comment: @user2958635 "RIVETS" is the value of $ors['profile'], right? add quotation marks around it in the query string, and call me in the morning :P.

Comment: after I've what you've said 

the browser shows

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"CUTTING DISC 4""' at line 1

Comment: Really? hmmm... that means there are values in the database has some quotation marks. In this case it has 4" (four inches) but mysql is taking the quotation marks as part of the query... I'll update my answer.

Comment: @user2958635 I've updated (as you can see)... tell me if it gives you any problems.

Comment: but when Im using those sames codes they are working. Im only changing the TABLE NAME. Is the problem is in the table itself?

Comment: @user2958635 the problem is raised by the data in that table, it contains values that are not safe to be sent unescaped via sql. In general, it is a good idea to do not trust any source. You either sanitize the data before sending it to the database or use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
mysqli_error()
```

to

```
mysqli_error($link)
```

in each of the places where it occurs.

ie 4th line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $strQuery) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

and 8th line:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $strQuery) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: after I've put the $link

the error showed in my browser

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"CUTTING DISC 4""' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
mysqli_error()
```

by

```
mysqli_error($link)
```

By the way, if the error message is as clear, you don't need to ask here. Just read the manual.